# How can I create a zip folder of a folder in which many files and folders exist?

Tags: java, file-io, zip

I am using below code to create zip folder. My zip folder has been created but when we extract this zip folder then some error is thrown :- No Archives Found.

```
try {
        File inFolder = new File("D:\\zextra\\ab");
        File outFolder = new File("D:\\zextra\\ab.zip");
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFolder)));
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
        String files[] = inFolder.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFolder.getPath() + "/" + files[i]), 1000);
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i]));
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1000)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            out.closeEntry();
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: *"some error is thrown"* 1) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you paste the error you are getting? For me this code is working. I am able to open the generated archive and files from the zip file.

Comment: No error thrown by this code when i create zip folder.But i getting error when we extract zip folder by using WinRAR software then wraning message is comeing:-No Archives Found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also close `FileOutputStream`. ZipOutputStream closing could be not enough.

See for example http://www.journaldev.com/957/java-zip-example-to-zip-single-file-and-a-directory-recursively

They use `fos.close();`